# What is the term for creating a network from scratch?

Tags: network, terminology

As part of my PhD, I developed a simple way of creating a road network splitting up collected coordinates based on where they cross. I know the standard method is to use a shapefile (or similar) as the network, and match coordinates to it. However, I was not interested in all junctions, simply the junctions where the recorded vehicles went more than one way.

What would be the term for creating a new network?

I have tried looking it up multiple times, but always get directed towards ready-made networks and their analysis.

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are doing, and 'the standard method' is rarely connected to *shapefiles*; but I'd say what you presumably are doing is *modeling* a network. However, *creating* is more or less the essence of it, so why not go with that term? *Deriving* a network from your base data could be what you are doing. *Building* the network (or graph) is also frequently used.

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to keep it succinct. I am recording audio data for different roads, with a view to comparing routes. Everything is being stored in a timeseries database (as roads may change over time). I'm querying and processing data with python. My created network enables me to query all data from a certain stretch of road, along which all recordings traverse the full distance, for averaging, etc.

Comment: Regarding the shapefiles, I am not from a GIS background and looking up network analysis in python threw up importing networks (often as shapefiles).

Comment: fair enough, didn't want to sound rude. that's a wild approach you describe there; could be a very interesting source for traffic modeling if I get that right.

Comment: It's ok, your comment was helpful, thank you. Would you say there is a standard way of creating a network?